# Changing behaviour of double quotes when >> a stringstream

Tags: c++, stl, stringstream

Here is what I'm trying to do:

say I have a stringstream. Then I `<< "\"hello world\" today";`

then when I do

```
sstr >> myString1 >> myString2;
```

I would like myString1 to have "hello world"
and for myString2 to have "today"

Is there a way, possibly with a manipulator, to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You either need to change the stream type (and hence the parsing semantics) or use your own string type (and hence change the parsing semantics in your overloaded op>>).

Instead, consider writing a function, similar to getline, which parses a possibly-quoted "word" out of a stream:

```
getqword(sstr, myString1);
getqword(sstr, myString2);
if (sstr) { /* both succeeded */ }
```

Note that input into a std::string already terminates at whitespace, so you only need to handle peeking ahead for a quote and then handle edge cases, of which there are plenty:

- escapes (quotes inside quotes)

  - the three prevalent styles are disallowed, backslash, and doubled quote; each has advantages and disadvantages
- spanning multiple lines (can \n be included?)

  - this is often a data error, so disallowing it can be a big help in some circumstances
- what happens if a quoted word ends next to another word?

  - `"\"hello world\"today"`
- skip leading whitespace?

  - unlike getline, it makes sense to honor the stream's skipws flag, but I could see that going the other way in rare circumstances
  - the istream sentry will handle this for you
- don't forget to use the stream's traits and locale, or use methods which already do that!

  - or document your assumptions

Comment: ITs easy to implement using std::getline(istream, string, terminator). Just set the terminator to '"' and it will stop reading at the first quite.

Comment: @Martin: That depends on specific decisions for escaping and line handling which you don't always want.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you expand in your answer.

Comment: @Martin: When either the "backslash" or "doubled quote" decisions are made for escaping, or "no" for spanning multiple lines; all mentioned above.

Answer (score 5):

Short Answer: No

Long Answer:
There are no manipulates that will do that for you.

Alternative Answer:

You could write your own type that could be used in conjunction with the stream operators do do this task.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


class QuotedWord
{
    public:
        operator std::string const& () const { return data;}

    private:
        std::string     data;
      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, QuotedWord const& value);
      {
        return str << value.data;
      }
      friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, QuotedWord& value);
      {
        char x;
        str >> x;
        if ((str) && (x == '"'))
        {
            std::string extra;
            std::getline(str, extra, '"');
            value.data = std::string("\"").append(extra).append("\"");
        }
        else
        {
            str.putback(x);
            str >> value.data;
        }
        return str;
      }
};
```

Then it can be used normally.

```
int main()
{
    QuotedWord  word;

    std::cin >> word;
    std::cout << word << "\n";

    // Easily convertible to string
    std::string tmp = word;
    std::cout << tmp << "\n"

    // because it converts to a string easily it can be used where string is needed.
    std::vector<std::string>   data;

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<QuotedWord>(std::cin),
              std::istream_iterator<QuotedWord>(),

              // Notice we are using a vector of string here.
              std::back_inserter(data)
             );
}

> ./a.out
"This is" a test    // Input
"This is"           // Output
"This is"
```

Comment: Doesn't handle the case of `"input"` (no intervening whitespace between quotes) or `"input"more`, which also, if implemented this way, requires more than the one guaranteed putback.

Comment: You forgot to check if str >> x succeeded or failed and need to skip leading whitespace if skipws is set, which is easiest done with an istream sentry.  Otherwise, this is very close to what I was imagining in my answer.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: All fixed. Thanks to code taken from @Christian Ammer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701535/changing-behaviour-of-double-quotes-when-a-stringstream/4701684#4701684

Comment: @ Fred Nurk: Delibrately don;t check if >> operator worked or not. As I can;t do anything useful with the result. The user of oeprator >> will just have to check the state of the stream (as they would with std::string). I don't want to change the behavior for skipws I want it to behave in the same way as std::string which it does now.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, you need a "wrapper" class that terminates where you want it to.

```
struct QuotedStringReader
{
   std::string& str;
   QuotedStringReader( std::string& s ) : str( s ) {}
};

std::istream operator>>( std::istream&, const QuotedStringReader& qsr );

std::string s, s2;
stream >> QuotedStringReader( s ) << s2;
```

Note that this is a rare occasion where you stream into a const - because you can write to the internal str even though it is const, and this way I can pass in a temporary.

Actually as you probably don't know what you are about to read you could simply call it "TokenReader" which reads whatever you define as a "token".

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  Not that particular way.  You could create a "strong typedef" for string though and design a new operator>> for it that behaves that way.

Answer (score 1):

In c++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string in = "String with spaces, and embedded \"quotes\" too";
    std::string out;

    ss << std::quoted(in);
    std::cout << "read in     [" << in << "]\n"
              << "stored as   [" << ss.str() << "]\n";

    ss >> std::quoted(out);
    std::cout << "written out [" << out << "]\n";
}
```

Output:

```
read in     [String with spaces, and embedded "quotes" too]
stored as   ["String with spaces, and embedded \"quotes\" too"]
written out [String with spaces, and embedded "quotes" too]
```

*Source:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. It's because if you look into the implementation of `operator>>` for `basic_istream` which is in fact called when you do `sstr >> myString1`, you will see this inside the `for` loop:

```
else if (_Ctype_fac.is(_Ctype::space,_Traits::to_char_type(_Meta)))
   break;// whitespace, quit
```

Means, once you get "space", Quit. So you cannot keep adding characters to your `myString1` once you get space.

Note this is MSVC++ implementation, but I'm sure the equivalent you'll found in all implementation!

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the input stream operator and include the parsing semantics there.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::string& out)
{
    char c;
    is >> c;
    if (c == '\"')
    {
        std::getline(is, out, '\"');
        return is;
    }
    else
    {
        is.putback(c);
        return std::operator >>(is, out);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("\"hello world\" today");
    std::string test;
    while (iss >> test)
        std::cout << test << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Though this works. I don't like it because it leads to unexpected behavior. What happens if a colleague modifies your code unaware that you have defined a new overload of the >> operator for string. The problem may not even show up during his unit tests but blow up in the real world.

Comment: You should not overload operators on stdlib types where a type of your own isn't involved.